# How to not care about the exact type of a generic in a base class?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have the following abstract base class `Connection<Message, RawData>`, that leaves the specifics of sending a message to the subclasses:

```
abstract class Connection<Message, RawData> {
  messageHandlers: Array<(msg: Message) => void> = [];

  constructor(public path: string) {}

  public send(message: Message): void {
    const data = this.formatData(message);
    this.realSend(data);
  }

  abstract connect(): void;
  abstract formatData(message: Message): RawData;
  abstract realSend(data: RawData): void;
}
```

I then have multiple subclasses that fill in the specifics, such as `SomeConnection`:

```
import {Buffer} from 'node:buffer';

interface SomeMessage {
  id: number;
  value: number;
}

class SomeConnection extends Connection<SomeMessage, Buffer> {
  override connect(): void {
    someLibrary.connect(this.path);
    someLibrary.on('message', (data: SomeMessage) => {
      for (const handler of this.messageHandlers) {
        handler(data);
      }
    });
  }

  override formatData(message: SomeMessage): Buffer {
    const str = `${message.id};${message.value}`
    return Buffer.from(str);
  }

  override realSend(data: Buffer): Promise<void> {
    return someLibrary.write(this.path, data);
  }
}
```

Now I have buttons that, when clicked, send different messages to different connections. One button can have multiple connections it needs to operate on.

I've created a common base class `Button<Connections>`, that performs some operations on its connections without caring about their exact subtypes:

```
abstract class Button<Connections extends Record<string, Connection< ??? >>> {  // PROBLEM HERE!
  constructor(public connections: Connections) {}
  abstract onMouseClick(): void;
}
```

And here's how I intended to specify the class in a subclass:

```
interface MyButtonConnections {
  some: SomeConnection;
  other: OtherConnection; // Imagine this exists.
}

class MyButton extends Button<MyButtonConnections> {
  constructor(public id: number, public clickCount: number = 0) {
    super({
      some: new SomeConnection('http://localhost:1234'),
      other: new OtherConnection('http://example.com'),
    });
  }

  override onMouseClick(): void {
    this.clickCount++;
    this.connections.some.send({id: this.id, value: this.clickCount});
    this.connections.other.send(this.clickCount); // Imagine "Other" takes a number in send();
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is the declaration of the abstract Button class:

```
abstract class Button<Connections extends Record<string, Connection>>
```

Since `Connection` itself uses generics, how do I tell TypeScript that I don't care what kind of connections they are?

Comment: Could you wrap this up into a [TypeScript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) please? (Ideally something [minimal](/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and with adequate placeholders for "Imagine this exists" things.) (Beware [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386543/why-does-my-typescript-playground-link-break-when-i-use-insert-hyperlink) when posting the link in the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your example correctly, your `Button` base class doesn't even care if the connections are indeed connections. Heck, it doesn't even care if there are connections at all.

```
abstract class Button {
  abstract onMouseClick(): void;
}

class MyButton extends Button {
  private readonly connections = {
    some: new SomeConnection('http://localhost:1234'),
    other: new OtherConnection('http://example.com'),
  } as const;
  public clickCount: number = 0;

  constructor(public readonly id: number) {}

  override onMouseClick(): void {
    this.clickCount++;
    this.connections.some.send({id: this.id, value: this.clickCount});
    this.connections.other.send(this.clickCount);
  }
}
```

If your `Button` class really needs to know about connections, then I would abstract out the parts that it cares about.

```
// for example
type MessageSink = { getSentMessageCount(): number; }
abstract class Button<Connections extends Record<string, MessageSink>> {
  ...
```

You could also use the `unknown` type as a generic parameter, but I don't recommend that here, I wouldn't add unnecessary constraints to the base.